# Where does FileLoggingSession in Windows 8.1 keep the log files?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 introduced a [FileLoggingSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.fileloggingsession.aspx) class to log messages to a file. The docs say:

> The FileLoggingSession class sends logged messages to disk files as
>   they are logged. The FileLoggingSession class uses sequential logging,
>   which means that all messages are sent to a disk file, and a
>   sequential history of messages is retained. This is distinct from the
>   LoggingSession class, which sends logged messages to disk on-demand,
>   and this happens when there's a problem and the immediate history of
>   in-memory messages is needed for analysis.

But I can't find the log file. I found a `Log-MySession-1.etl` file in the `LocalState/Logs` but it is only 1kb and doesn't seem to contain the logs. Here's some test code I wrote:

```
    FileLoggingSession loggingSession;
    LoggingChannel loggingChannel;

    loggingSession = new FileLoggingSession("MySession");
    loggingChannel = new LoggingChannel("MyChannel");
    loggingSession.AddLoggingChannel(loggingChannel);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        loggingChannel.LogMessage("Test message: " + i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be available via the `LogFileGenerated` event ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.fileloggingsession.logfilegenerated.aspx)):

The event arguments `LogFileGeneratedEventArgs` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.logfilegeneratedeventargs.aspx)) include a `File` property.

Answer (score 0):

The ".etl" file contains the log in binary format.
Use following command from command prompt to extract the logs in XML format:

```
c:\ tracerpt.exe my_etl_file_name.etl -of XML -o readable_logs.xml
```

You can opt to call this from code after receiving a log creation event.
Another option for C++/PInvoke is using [OpenTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ProcessTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CloseTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363686%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods on ".etl" files after they have been uploaded to your sever.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this.  After you create the FileLoggingSession hook the LogFileGenerated event handler.  Then in the your event handler method dump out the args.File.Path.

```
    public FileLoggingHelper( ...) 
    {
        m_fileLoggingSession = new FileLoggingSession( "mylogsession" );
        m_fileLoggingSession.LogFileGenerated += FileLoggingSession_LogFileGenerated;
    }

    private void FileLoggingSession_LogFileGenerated(IFileLoggingSession sender, LogFileGeneratedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "generated " + args.File.Path);
        ...
    }
```